# Why does Mathematica give the wrong answer for this integral, and how can I correct it?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, complex

Mathematica is getting the following integral completely wrong:

```mma
$Assumptions = a > 0;
Integrate[1/k (E^-(k + a)^2 - E^-(k - a)^2), {k, 0, ∞}]
(* I E^-a^2 π *)
```

Note that the integrand is real at every point in the domain, yet Mathematica returns a pure imaginary. I tried the option `PrincipalValue->True` but to no avail (note the removable singularity at $k=0$; the integrand is well behaved and bounded for all $k>0$.)

1. Why does Mathematica mess this up?
2. How can I get Mathematica to give me the right answer?

---

UPDATE:

With a bit of manipulation, I found that the original integral is equal to the following principal value integral, which Mathematica seems to evaluate correctly:

```mma
Integrate[1/(k - a) E^-k^2, {k, -∞, ∞}, PrincipalValue -> True]
(* -2 Sqrt[π] DawsonF[a] *)
```

So (2) is now partially answered. Nonetheless, it would still be nice to know if there is a way to accomplish (2) without transforming the integral as above.

See also [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3844997/how-can-i-solve-this-integral-hilbert-transform-of-a-gaussian) where I ask about how this analytical solution could be derived from scratch.

Comment: You have two `Integrate`s yet only one variable range. You also don't need to nest it

Comment: The integral stays unevaluated. I don't get the answer from a fresh notebook. `PrincipalValue` isn't really relevant here.

Comment: @flinty Maybe it's a version difference? I have version 12.

Comment: I have 12.1.1.0. Rubi can't handle it either. Can you post the anti-derivative result (without the `{k,0,Infinity}`) and check if you can differentiate it back to the integrand? It could be a bug in v12.0 that it produced an incorrect result, when in fact this integral is much harder. Only with a == 0, it involves `ExpIntegralEi`.

Comment: It gives me the unevaluated integral when I don't specify a domain of integration. So this is one of those integrals with no "nice" antiderivative, but that may have a closed-form analytical result when treated as a definite integral.

Comment: After writing it slightly differently, I'm now getting the result you got but 2x because I integrated over the whole range: `Integrate[(
 Exp[-(k - a)^2] - Exp[-(k + a)^2])/k, {k, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]` `-2 I E^-a^2 \[Pi]`